# using Html.ActionLink with complex objects(contains with other objects)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, razor, html.actionlink

So right to the point, I'm trying to call a controller method with the Html.ActionLink, as I did in other ocasions, only this time, I am giving it an Object that itself contains another Object and a string. But the object always comes as null. I'm keeping the Login in the ViewBag (it is there, I checked).

The classes:

```
public class Login
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")] // make the field required
    [Display(Name = "Username")]  // Set the display name of the field
    public string Username{ get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password{ get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Company")]
    public string Company{ get; set; }

}

public class Filter
    {
        public Login loginInfo;
        public string idDocument;
    }
```

The Html.ActionLink call:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "DetailOrder", "Home", new {loginInfo = new { Company = ViewBag.loginInfo.Company, Username = ViewBag.loginInfo.Username, Password = ViewBag.loginInfo.Password }, idDocument = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumDoc) }, htmlAttributes:null)
```

The controller method

```
public ViewResult DetailOrder(Filter afilter)
{
    ...
    return View(ans);
}
```

At this point, i've tried a few things, in the ActionLink, by giving the object as:

```
2-new { loginInfo=ViewBag.loginInfo, idDocument= @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumDoc)}
3-new { Username=ViewBag.loginInfo.Username, Password=ViewBag.loginInfo.Password, Company=ViewBag.loginInfo.Company, idDocument= @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumDoc)}
4-new { afilter = new {loginInfo=ViewBag.loginInfo, idDocument= @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumDoc)} }
```

I made it work by changing the controller method header to:

```
public ViewResult DetailOrder(Login loginInfo, string idDocument)
```

and then using the nr3 object composition in the ActionLink. But this is not re-usable coding...
I now really want to know how do I use ActionLink with a complex Object. Is it even possible? I have not found an example in the ms tutorials.

Thanks

Comment: The framework is meant to turn an HTTP request `?a=1&b=2&c=3` into something .NET can understand. I don't see why this should be possible

Comment: Are you passing a real password in the query string? If you already have the properties why not persist them in some storage or session?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I'm using a rest architecture, this was the way I found so I don't need to control that on server side.

Comment: @beautifulcoder for what I read in the answer below, I think you're right, maybe i'll have to do it in a different way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only build a route value dictionary from an object if that object contains only value types. Internally the helper use reflection to return the `.ToString()` value of each property in the object. In the following case

```
public class ObjectA
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ObjectB MyObject { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and attempt to create a route using `ObjectA`, the values would be

```
/.../..?Name=Daniel&MyObject=YourAssembly.ObjectB
```

The first value (name) could be correctly bound, but the second value would try to bind the string "YourAssembly.ObjectB" to `MyObject` which or course it cant, so `MyObject` will be `null`.

Its not clear why you would want to do this or what benefit you would achieve (passing all these extra query string parameters would soon exceed the limit and just slow down your app)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That raises me a question, so, if I override ToString() in the Class Login, to a format that is http request compatible, would it possibly work?

Comment: Haven't actually tried it so not sure. You would have to generate a query string in the `ToString()`, and what about cases where its the first query parameter (needs `?` rather that `&`). Means your `ToString()` method would be unusable anywhere except when generating route values. And you would soon exceed the Http limit for query string length and the app would crash. What you trying to do is a terrible design and I cant see why you would want to do it anyway.

Comment: After I made it work, I was just curious about it, I wanted to know why it wouldn't work. I fully understand your point, again, thank you for answering both my questions.